# How to use host DISPLAY within docker

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, unix, x11

How to use host `DISPLAY` within docker?

I setup `DISPLAY` within my docker instance and want to use it for my xapps. But this is what I'm getting:

```
me@178887a67067:/$ env | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=192.168.0.102:2

me@178887a67067:/$ xterm &
[1] 11
me@178887a67067:/$ xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: 192.168.0.102:2

[1]+  Exit 1                  xterm
```

How to allow xapps within docker to connect and use my host `DISPLAY` *without* using host-network (`--network host`)? Thanks.

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

**[Amend]**

I know it must sounds like an FAQ, but I've tried all the methods from the following sites, but none is working for me:

- http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI
- https://iamhow.com/How_To/Docker_How_To.html#1484268
- https://forums.docker.com/t/still-not-sure-how-to-run-gui-apps-in-docker-containers/79103/3
- [xhost command for docker GUI apps (Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43015536/)

Using the simplest solution from 
https://iamhow.com/How_To/Docker_How_To.html#1484268 as an example:

```
$ xhost +local:
non-network local connections being added to access control list

$ docker run -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro image
# env | grep DISPLAY
DISPLAY=192.168.0.102:2

# xterm & 
Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user.
...
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s

[1]+  Exit 1                  xterm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though this question is very old and many people may have similar issue/question.

I searched google and tried all the methods from different website. But none worked. Then I used host **pid** in docker and it worked.

Try using host **pid** in the docker.

```
$ xhost +local:
$ docker run --pid=host -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:ro image
```

Comment: Bravo!! What's your OS? My Ubuntu 21.10 has everything works out of the box after I just set DISPLAY within docker client session, tested with simple `xclip` though.

Comment: My OS is Fedora 35.